# Chosing a GeoCMS server collaboration tool

Tags: open-source-gis

I have seen a few things about different GeoCms. Researching these, none of them by default to actually seem to be a GeoCMS. Somehow when you hook these up to mapserver they become a GeoCMS. I do not quite understand how this exactly works and I am wondering if there are any good GeoCMS's that are good for digital collaboration (for example if you cannot speak with the user in real life) and something easy for the non-techy. I have looked at Wordpress, TikiWiki and Drupal but do not understand how they are GEOCm's

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  At the moment I think your question may be to broad for our focussed Q&A format but with some edits (you can use the button beneath it) you should be able to bring it on-topic.  For example, if you were to list the GeoCMS software that you have already investigated and say why they do not meet your requirements, then that would save potential answerers from repeating your steps.  Perhaps the focus (and title) of your question should be "Finding GeoCMS with in-built map server?"

Comment: are you looking for mapping collaborative tool ?

Comment: I am looking for a collaborative mapping tool that I can set parameters for certain items to/be certain longitudinal paramters and all, features beyond just place markers.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Cartaro](http://cartaro.org/) which is probably what you're looking for, namely a *Geospatial CMS*. It is based on Drupal and manages for you user access right between Drupal, PostGIS and GeoServer and allows you to do collaborative tasks.